# Obwohl sich das nicht besonders anhört vs. Obwohl das sich nicht besonders anhört

Tags: word-order, reflexive, objects

> Das hört sich nicht besonders an. Die Serie ist wahnsinnig lustig.

We can combine the two statements into this:

> Obwohl sich das nicht besonders anhört, ist die Serie wahnsinnig lustig.

I'm almost certain about this, but can we also say:

> Obwohl das sich nicht besonders anhört, ist die Serie wahnsinnig lustig.

?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you said, the standard word order order is

> Obwohl sich das nicht besonders anhört, ...

If you have a reason, I see no problem in changing it to

> Obwohl das sich nicht besonders anhört, ...

I would normally stick to the standard order wth this sentence. While it can generally make sense to change standard word order to emphasize certain parts of the sentence, here it doesn't seem to have any discernible purpose, so the changed order sounds less fluent. I don't know your context though.

If you wanted to emphasize the subject, for example if the subject were a special aspect of the TV show that you wanted to emphasize, e.g. "der Plot", the second word order would indeed make more sense:

> Obwohl der Plot sich nicht besonders anhört, ist die Serie wahnsinnig lustig.

Comment: I disagree. I think the first, standard word order is correct, and the second one is wrong, not colloquial.

Comment: @Raketenolli Why do you think so? If anything, I'm rather in doubt if I should even state that it's colloquial.  https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/Stellung-des-Reflexivpronomens-sich

Comment: Edited, I took out my feeling about it even being colloquial.